# how can I define a value for model's field in symfony?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm building an app for the company I work for in symfony, non the less the app might be  pretty useful outside our company so we decided to write it in a more general form so we can make it multi company. I'm facing a problem on how to define a default value for a field that is going to be in every single model (company_id) so we don't need to select which company we belong to every time we want to add data. can anyone help me?
I've tried

```
class TestForm extends BaseTestForm
{

    function configure()
    {
        $this->setDefault('company_id', '1');
    }
}
```

and when I submit the form I get a missing value for model ....

Comment: Are you submitting the field `company_id` in the data you're binding to the form by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I did it, in the action of course, before the processForm and after the $this->form = new TestForm();

I used:

public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
{

```
...
$this->form->getObject()->setCompanyId('1');
...
```

}